# How to type like this?

Tags: linux, newlines

I was reading Shell Programming in Unix, Linux and OS X, 4th Edition.

In P.112, it showed an example like this

```
$ lines=one'
> 'two
$ echo "$lines"
one
two
$ lines=ones\
> two
$ echo "$lines"
onetwo
$
```

I was stucked in first sentence.

What I try is like this

```
jackson@jackson-VirtualBox:~$ lines=one'>'two
jackson@jackson-VirtualBox:~$ echo "$lines"
one>two
jackson@jackson-VirtualBox:~$ $lines=one'>'two
one>two=one>two: command not found
jackson@jackson-VirtualBox:~$ lines=one \n '>'two
n: command not found
jackson@jackson-VirtualBox:~$ lines=one' \n>'two
jackson@jackson-VirtualBox:~$ echo "$lines"
one \n>two
jackson@jackson-VirtualBox:~$ lines=one'>'two
jackson@jackson-VirtualBox:~$ lines=one'\n>'two
jackson@jackson-VirtualBox:~$ echo "$lines"
one\n>two
jackson@jackson-VirtualBox:~$ lines=one\n>two
jackson@jackson-VirtualBox:~$ echo "$lines"
onen
```

My question is : How to type

```
$ lines=one'
> 'two
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there are several solutions to get a newline inside a var, but I believe that you are actually asking about this:

On a new prompt,

1. type <kbd>lines=one</kbd>
2. type a single quote `'` and press <kbd>enter</kbd>
3. A '>' prompt will appear waiting for you to type.
4. type <kbd>'</kbd> and <kbd>two</kbd>
5. Press <kbd>enter</kbd>, done.

Of course you can get a newline inside a variable with:

```
lines=$'one\ntwo'            # in bash, zsh
lines=$(printf 'one\ntwo')   # in any shell
```

For example. If you need more solutions, just ask.

Comment: Thanks for answer!

Comment: You are welcome ! @Jacky

Answer (score 4):

This is being typed as:

```
lines=one'
'two
```

i.e. enter is being pressed after the first quote.

Because it's inside a quote, bash treats the next input line (beginning with an end-quote) as part of the previous line.  The `>`  is just a prompt from bash indicating that it's ready to accept more input to continue the previous line - it is not meant to be typed.

The prompt is the value of the `$PS2` variable, aka the "secondary prompt string".   This is used for continued/secondary input lines, while `$PS1` is used for primary input lines.   Try `declare -p PS1 PS2` to see what they're both defined as on your system - it's pretty common for people to customise their PS1, but far less common to customise PS2 (so it's probably at the default of `>` ).

Another way of doing the same thing, with a modern version of bash (and some other bourne-like shells is):

```
lines=$'one\ntwo'
```

Using `$'...'` instead of just `'...'` tells bash to interpret escape codes (like `\n` for newline) in the string.

Comment: I won, just once :-)   .  Never mind, it is a great answer anyway,